# How can I update a Django QuerySet, so that it doesn't return cached data?

Tags: django, django-views

The QuerySet in my Django ListView view doesn't automatically update when I create a new record in the model. The Django admin updates and the database updates, but the view does not update.

I've come to realise that this is happening because the QuerySet is using cached data.

To re-execute the QuerySet on a get request, I have unsuccessfully tried various versions of the code below...

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.user = self.request.user
    queryset = Strategy.objects.filter(user=self.user)
    updated_queryset = queryset.update()
    return updated_queryset
```

Instead of updating my QuerySet each time the webpage is refreshed, this is returning an empty QuerySet.

What do I need to do to update the QuerySet on a GET request?

The entire view...

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, FormView
from .models import Strategy, Version
from .forms import StrategyForm, VersionForm, ToolForm


class StrategyListView(ListView):
    model = Strategy
    context_object_name = 'strategy_list'
    template_name = 'simulator/strategy_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user = self.request.user
        return Strategy.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

Comment: Remove the call to `.update()`, this is a method for updating multiple records in one go not for clearing any sort of caches

Comment: Done. Any advice for clearing the cache?

Comment: Have you enabled the per-view or per-site cache? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

Comment: If you add a random querystring to the URL (`/api/path/?foo=bar`) do you get the updated data?

Comment: If the above does not work, it's possible that you have a queryset cached somewhere else. To verify this, do you get the updated data when you restart your Django app?

Comment: I've enabled per-site cache. When I restart the app or when I logout and login, I see the updated data.

Comment: The per-site cache is probably the culprit then, you could disable caching for this one view?

Comment: The random querystring doesn't do anything. This is happening on other views as well. It just started when I switched my views from functions to Classes. I'd rather not switch them back to functions, but I may have to do so.

Comment: Can you add the entire view to the question? Switching to class based views should not cause this to happen

Comment: I think you're onto it with the caching, I'll have another look at this. I've tried to recreate the error other projects, and I can't recreate it...but the other projects didn't have per-site cache enabled. I'll check there. Thanks.